# Magnetization of coin on a railway track

Tags: electromagnetism

The rumor was you could make a magnet by leaving a piece of iron on a train track. The train going over it would magnetize it.

Is it true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is almost a duplicate to [can you magnetize iron with a hammer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/18340/can-you-magnetize-iron-with-a-hammer/18341#comment43493_18341) . Have a look at it.

The only difference is that the rail lines are fixed in their north south direction for years. The iron in the lines themselves become magnetized and so the argument with the hammer should also hold , i.e. the small magnetic domains, momentarily freed by the impact,  reorient to the magnetic field direction of North South of the earth's magnetic field. If the coin partially melts under the weight of the train, even better. It should of course be made from a ferromagnetic metal.

Comment: during some mispent youth we used to place coins on a rail track.  the end result was a smeared out coin about 3cm in length...

Comment: @Nic did you check them for magnetisation?

Comment: unfortunately we weren't that advanced!  We just had fun squashing things...

Comment: @annav i actually did this a couple of times and also checked for magnetization, no it would't work

Comment: I am from India and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_Indian_coins) wiki article tells that the ones i used were made up of stainless steel

Comment: @Jack  stainless steel  is another story : http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=305611

Comment: well thx, i have no further interest in searching for what type of SS my country uses, anyways having some clarity on the topic will do anyway, thx for the quick responses @annav