# Coercivity of a ferromagnetic material?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I understand that coercivity is the field/force required to demagnetize/magnetize a ferromagnetic material.
What if we had two opposite magnetic fields of different strengths values H acting on the same ferromagnet what would happen?

**H1** = 50 Oe
**H2** = 10 Oe

The coercivity of the material is 0.5 Oe, what would happen? Will it stay magnetized to the stronger field(H1)? Or **magnetization = 0**?

Answer (score 0):

Magnetic field is additive, so if I understand you correctly your magnet would be in 40 Oe field in direction of H1. As this is more than coercivity magnet will be magnetized by that effective field.

As a sidenote: in ferromagnetic materials it's not that easy to obtain zero magnetization. In zero field you would have spontaneous magnetization. But this can be (almost) done by applying alternating field with amplitude lowering over time. See [degaussing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degaussing) on Wikipedia for example (section about CRTs to be precise). Magnetization is not entirely removed, but randomized, and it's amplitude vastly diminished.

EDIT:
If you have no magnetization and you don't exceed coercive field you will have magnetization which is not permanent, and will vanish soon after you take your field away. If you exceed coercivity you will get permanent magnetization which will decrease slightly if you take field away. Now if you change direction of field to opposite you will get decreasing magnetization with growing field. At field strength equal to coercivity you will get zero magnetization, and then direction of your magnetization will switch if you keep increasing field any further. Look up histeresis curve. [Here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/solids/hyst.html) you have it really nicely detailed. In your example all of this is unimportant as field strength is much higher than coercivity so sample will magnetize in direction of stronger field no matter what.

Comment: So the ferromagnet's magnetization is "dropped". However, we are ignoring the coercivity of the material being 0.5 Oe. It does not matter how much field strength is present only, but also the coercivity of the material itself how strong of a field it "needs" to become magnetized and demagnetized.

Comment: H is a vector field, a measure of strength. It's not considered a kind of force. So by introducing the ferromagnetic material to an external force(Mechanical Stresses) what would be the result? Since my previous argument was two H vectors, and the ferromagnet will react to H = 40 Oe, they are fields opposing each other. Now if a force is applied to cause a disruption to the domain's alignment what would be the result? Assuming the field still exists.

Comment: But H field **is** a bit like force. Certainly so if we consider magnetic system. Mechanical stress doesn't have to influence magnetization much. There are few effects that can couple stress to magnetization. Most important are magnetostriction and piezomagnetism (which of these two depends on material). There could be other indirect couplings, but they are much weaker. So to answer question what would happen - not much, probably just minor change of magnetization, probably hard to detect.

Comment: Mechanical stress would not influence magnetization, however, could influence demagnetization if it was constant. Imagine causing constant mechanical stresses to such a ferromagnet, it's domains will disrupt. Even if H 40 Oe is present. My theory is that here we are applying to forces. Even if we did not apply an equivalent amount of force in mechanical stress it still weakens the magnetization by a huge factor. I'm I correct here?

Comment: For very high stresses (or pressures) there could be phase change into non-ferromagnetic one. But this is usually huge (tens of GPa) pressure. Stress doesn't influence magnetization that much, because it's related to spin. And a slight bit to other magnetic moments, like nuclei moments, and orbital moment of electrons. You would have to change (or at least deform) crystal structure to change spin system. It's very weakly coupled to anything. First order approximation would be to treat it as something completely separate, dependent only on magnetic fields.

Comment: And even though spin is property of electron - just like charge - there usually isn't much of a coupling between charge and magnetization. And as a sidenote - it seems to me that stress equivalent to even small magnetic field in terms of interaction would be more than enough to tear any material apart.

Comment: That information is just amazing to imagine. Really beautiful how things work huh!

Comment: What would be the best and easiest method to demagnetize this ferromagnet in the state of an exterior field? Heating it up beyond the Tc? That requires mega amounts of energy in the form of heat. Mega Joules... I thought that by dropping it causing minor vibrations would demagnetize it.

Comment: Short of heating up beyond Curie point and cooling without any field applied there is one option. Alternating field decreasing with time. It could be as simple as RLC circuit. There are dozens of this type of demagnetizers everywhere. They are often used by watchmakers to demagnetize screwdrivers and other tools.

Comment: And there is a section on this in Wikipedia. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet#Demagnetizing_ferromagnets . It seems somewhat inaccurate though. When you examine list of demagnetization methods you will have of course going above curie point, then above lowering field, and further three points that are really equivalent to it, maybe considered in a slightly different manner. Last point is hammering. So it seems that you can demagnetize magnet mechanically to some degree. Here http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/18340/can-you-magnetize-iron-with-a-hammer it's discussed a bit.

Comment: This question deals with magnetizing, but nevertheless it's close enough to be of some merit. Also it seems that if you have coercivity high enough this will not work, because even depinning domain walls would not bring coercivity down enough so that demagnetization could occur.

Comment: Well, I believe it possible to fully demagnetize a ferromagnet via hammering, from a university lecture that is what exactly happened, a magnetized ferromagnet with low coercivity was dropped to the ground and lost it's magnetization completely. I'm trying to research to discover what would happen hammering a ferromagnet while placed in a exterior magnetic field. There are to opposite kinds of forces acting on the domains. So, i'm not sure what happens here.

Comment: Actually it could be interesting, because my main question was what would happen if there are two opposing fields, they are two vectors and simple algebra would show the result here. However, mechanical stress like hammering is a whole different thing. Specifically vibrations(shockwaves) generated due to hammering, if they we're in the magnitude of the field intensity H(tot) = 40 Oe it would fully demagnetize the material. So, this is really interesting yet confusing. unfortunately there is not much info. about this...

Comment: Well you probably would get it magnetized. But hammering can only influence those ferromagnets that show change in magnetization due to domain wall motion (most iron magnets used for demonstration). In this case what you do with vibration is detach domain wall from defects. You can get demagnetization if field from neighbouring domains isn't enough to hold magnetization. If you did this in magnetic field domain would set itself in it's direction. Vibration doesn't influence magnetization directly, it just makes it easy for fields to rotate magnetization.

Comment: Now I must admit as a pure physicist had different mechanism of magnetization rotation in mind - not domain wall movability but rotation of magnetization in domain itself. This is more common in high purity samples that are object of fundamental studies (i mean not application oriented here). This is much less susceptible to mechanical stress than the other case. And theoretical models I'm accustomed with just plainly neglect it. But there must be coupling also in this case, or else coercivity would be zero. In theory you can just put damping in, and completely forget about why it's there.

Comment: So going from theoretical model to experiment is not that easy for magnets. You have to take into account real structure of your material. For example if you have a lot of defects coercive field will be higher, even if you use same exact material. Even shape of magnet can play role. And real structure is tough to handle. You can only calculate some statistics. That's probably why there is not a whole lot of references there.

Comment: The same result would happen from constant vibrations due to hammering? I assume what you stated is from one strike. I propose the process being constant.

Comment: It's only quantitative change. With more hammering you can dislodge more domain walls, but when they are all oriented (and field is still on) it's no longer doing anything.